# All objects in an array keep getting "updated" when I add a new object

Tags: java, android, arrays

I really didn't want to have to ask this online, but I couldn't figure it out myself.

I'm writing an Android app to keep track of the strategy of some Go-Kart endurance races (managing the driver-changes).

For every Stint object(= the part of the race between two driver changes) I set a Driver object and a start time (Integer[2]. Index 0 is the hour, index 1 is the minute).
Every stint will be put in a Stint Array.

After creating a new Stint object (and putting it into the next spot of the array) I go the previous element of the array and set its end time to the start time (of the new object), which was the constructor argument for the new stint. So startTime of the new stint = end time of the old stint. Makes sense, right? I need this to calculate the duration.

BUT here's the problem:
Everytime I create a new Stint object ALL start times of the previous objects will be overwritten to the new time. So when the first stint begins at 10:00 and the second one begins at 10:35, the start time of the first is all of the sudden 10:35 as well.

I think it's some kind of reference-based problem but I don't understand it. The Driver objects that I pass to a new Stint object will not be changed - only the start time!!

This is the method for the first stint (= race start).
pickedTime comes from an Android TimePicker Dialog.
cDI --> currentDriverIndex
stintIndex is 0 at this point.

```
public void createFirstStint(String driver, Integer[] pickedTime) {

    for (int i = 0; i < AMOUNTOFDRIVERS; i++) {
        if (driver.equalsIgnoreCase(driverArray[i].getName()))
            this.cDI = i;
    }

    driverArray[cDI].setDriving(true);
    driverOverviewArray[cDI].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

    Stint stint = new Stint(driverArray[cDI], pickedTime);
    stintArray[stintIndex] = stint;


}
```

This is the method for every other stint. Basically the same.
pDI --> previousDriverIndex. 
Here I create a new Stint object and put in the next spot of the array (stintIndex++).
After that I go to the previous array element [stintIndex -1] and set the end time. This works, but the start time will be overwritten as well.

```
private void createRegularStint(String driver, Integer[] pickedTime) {

    stintIndex++;

    pDI = cDI;

    for (int i = 0; i < AMOUNTOFDRIVERS; i++) {
        if (driver.equalsIgnoreCase(driverArray[i].getName()))
            this.cDI = i;
    }

    driverArray[pDI].setDriving(false);
    driverArray[cDI].setDriving(true);

    Stint stint = new Stint(driverArray[cDI], pickedTime);
    stintArray[stintIndex] = stint;
    stintArray[stintIndex - 1].setEnd(pickedTime, savePrevStintStartTime); // Sets
                                                                            // also
                                                                            // the
    // calculated duration
    int durationOfLastStint = stintArray[stintIndex - 1]
            .getDurationMinutes();
    driverArray[pDI].setTimeDriven(durationOfLastStint);
    race.addRaceTime(durationOfLastStint);

    updateCards();

    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= stintIndex; i++) {
        s += "Stint " + i + "| Start: "
                + timeMaker(stintArray[i].getStart()) + " Ende: "
                + timeMaker(stintArray[i].getEnd()) + " Fahrer:  "
                + stintArray[i].getDriver().getName() + "\n";

    }
```

And this is the Stint class which has of course all the setters & getters.
I initialize the end time with 999, but that was just some messing around of me.

```
public class Stint {

public Driver driver;
public Integer[] start;
public Integer[] end;
public int durationMinutes;

public Stint(Driver driver, Integer[] start) {

    this.driver = driver;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = new Integer[2];
    end[0] = 999;
    end[1] = 999;


}

/*
 * ************************************************
 */

public void calcStintDuration(Integer[] savePrevStintStartTime) {

    int minutes;

    minutes = end[1] - savePrevStintStartTime[1];
    if (minutes < 0)
        minutes *= (-1);

    this.durationMinutes = minutes;

}

/*
 * GETTER & SETTER*********************************
 */

public void setEnd(Integer[] end, Integer[] savePrevStintStartTime) {
    this.end = end;


}

public Driver getDriver() {
    return driver;
}

public Integer[] getStart() {
    return start;
}

public Integer[] getEnd() {
    return end;

}

public int getDurationMinutes() {
    return durationMinutes;
}

public void setDurationMinutes(int durationMinutes) {
    this.durationMinutes = durationMinutes;
}

/*
 * ************************************************
 */
```

}

For example:
When I enter 5 different Stints (14:00, 14:25, 14:39; 15:00, 15:15) then all previous Stint objects will have the start time 15:15, even though I never touch them after creation. Even when I mark the "start" variable of the Stint class as final this keeps happening.

Sorry guys, but I have no idea why this doesn't do what I want it to do. I also followed the debugger step by step but coulnd't figure out on which part of the code that happens. I hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: You're not adding a new object like you think you are.

Comment: because it is the same object ...

Comment: Welcome to java programming.  You are assigning the same object reference to each element in the array.  this means that every element in the array "points" to the same object.

Comment: Thank you guys. 
But how can I make sure that only as many objects as needed will be created. It could be four, it also could be 7! I can't tell at the beginning of a race. Of course I could create Object 1-10 at the beginning, but I thinks that's not very "clean".

Also why are still the correct Driver objects linked to the "different" Stint objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the times in the Stint constructor.

```
public class Stint {
    private Integer[] start;

    public Stint(Driver driver, Integer[] start) {
        this.start = Arrays.copyOf[start, start.length];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this dind't change anything :-( What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

So I guess the following part is wrong as well?

```
private void createRaceAndDriverObjects() {

    for (int i = 0; i < AMOUNTOFDRIVERS; i++) {
        Driver driver = new Driver(driverNamesArray[i], RACEDURATION);
        driverArray[i] = driver;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < stintArray.length; i++) {
        Stint stint = new Stint();
        stintArray[i] = stint;
    }

    this.race = new Race(driverArray, RACEDURATION);

}
```

That means that the Driver objects were the same the whole time.